# Can git show the lines of a file that were modified in another branch?

Tags: git, branch, branching-and-merging

Suppose I have a file and I am going to modify it in some branch. Also I have another branch where that file is already modified. At some point I am going to merge that 2 branches and I want to avoid possible merge conflict. That's why I want to know what lines of a file were already modified in another branch when editing the file so that I can decide whether should I continue editing or probably first merge another branch and continue editing.

Is it possible with git?

Comment: `git diff HEAD:./file another-branch:./file`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

Differentes between current branch and the other branch

```
git diff other-branch -- the-file
```

Now between the other branch and the point where that branch and our current branch diverged (in other words, changes introduced on that branch only):

```
git diff HEAD...other-branch -- the-file
```

Notice triple dot.